# How do I get to the "Home" in Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I feel really dumb for needing to ask this.  When I'm using the Play Store app, how do I get back to the main screen?  Currently I hit "Back" multiple times to get there, but if I have done a lot of browsing, the navigation history is very long, so I have to hit "Back" many times.

Is there a quick way to get back to the main Play Store screen without using the Back button?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you navigate the Play Store using the app, each app page has a left-arrow just below the status/notification bar. I have just tested this to 20 levels deep, and the arrow brings you to one of 2 places:

1. Play Store home directly, or,
2. that account's navigation menu, including Store Home as the first option.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the front page of Play Store, with a lot of history, it may be cumbersome and time-consuming to press the back key or the *up* key (the left arrow in the top-left). Below is an easier method. Note that this is only possible on devices after Gingerbread (**Android 3.0+**)

1. **Add** Play Store to your home screen from your app drawer. *Note: This is optional, but it will save you time in the future.*
2. After browsing for a while, open your recents by holding the **Home** button, or **Recents** button if you have one.
3. **Close Play Store** by swiping the thumbnail either to the left or to the right, or by clearing all recents, if you don't mind closing all the other apps that are open. *Note: Functionality to clear all recents may vary from device to device.*
4. Go to your home screen by pressing the **Home** button.
5. When you **open Play Store** again from your home screen, it will be back at the front page.